# Yii ajax image upload and resize

Tags: ajax, image, upload, yii, yii-extensions

I'm looking for a Yii extensions which allows to  :

1. upload in a form an image with ajax (with a progress bar)
2. resize this uploaded image
3. view the result of the new resized image in the same form

Do you know a good extension ?

Comment: Whathaveyoutried.com Or Which extensions you have tried till now? It is really a [Gorrila Vs Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) Al though it is asking  **Which Animal is best?**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about resize but you should try this great extension [XUpload](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload/) with documentation as [XUpload Workflow](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/348/xupload-workflow/)